# Make a link a certain shape in html

Tags: html, css

I am using a grid system to show off a team section for a website and in the grid system I have 8 sections which would have individual links that lead to other pages, and each of those 8 sections have a rounded image, I was wondering how I would be able to make the link conform to only the circle and not the previous square shape that came default:

**Note: this is not the full grid only a section**

```css
       //this makes the circle image
       div.Circ{
       margin: 20px auto;
       border-radius: 50%; 
       width: 200px;
       height: 200px;   
       }
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="six columns">
                        <a href="#2" id="myBtn"></a><div class="Circ"></div></a>
                        <div class="textUnderline">
                            <p>Mentors</p>
                        </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="six columns">
                    <a href="#1" id="driveBtn"><div class="Circ">
                        <img src="Images/bigboi.png">
                    </div>
                        <div class="textUnderline">
                            <p>Drive Team</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="six columns">
                    <a href="#3" id="mechBtn"><div class="Circ"></div>
                        <div class="textUnderline">
                            <p>Mechanical Executives</p>
                        </div></a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `overflow: hidden` to the `.Circ` divs:

```
div.Circ{
 margin: 20px auto;
 border-radius: 50%; 
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;  
 overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put the `Circ` class on the `<a>` rather than the `<div>`

You might not need the `div` at all, if you make the `a` a block element.